# Struggling with syntax with If....Then statements in model, Rails 3.2.13

Tags: if-statement, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to write an equation that calculates how long an employee has been hired to determine how much Vacation time they are eligible for. New hires get 10, after six years of employment they get an extra day a year, capping off at 10 extra days (on their 16th year). Some of these equations worked individually, but they don't work all together. So I'm having a syntax problem I think.

```
undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
```

The vacation_days section is what is breaking my app.

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  def years_employed
    (DateTime.now - hire_date).round / 365
  end

   def vacation_days
       if years_employed <= 6
         10
       end
        if years_employed > 6
         (years_employed.to_i - 6) + 10
       end
       if years_employed > 16
         (years_employed * 0) + 20  
       end
   end
```

end

Also, if you have any advice on a better way to go about this, please instruct me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want ends, you want elses, otherwise it's going to keep evaluating–so you were returning `nil` sometimes. Roughly:

```ruby
def vacation_days
   if years_employed <= 6
     10
   elsif years_employed <= 16
     years_employed + 4
   else
     20  
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I love how you reworked the equations too, it looks so much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

just as an alternative you can use a case statement along with ranges

```
 def vacation_days
    case years_employed
      when 0..6 then 10
      when 7..16 then years_employed+4
      else 20
   end
 end
```